# Can't set changePasswordAtNextLogin to true - Google Admin Directory V1 API Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, google-api, google-admin-sdk

I am using the `google-apis-admin_directory_v1` gem for Rails.
According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users#resource:-user), if you set the field `changePasswordAtNextLogin` to true in the insert user method it *Indicates if the user is forced to change their password at next login* however, when I have created users via the API with this attribute set to true it has not asked me to change my password.
Here is my method call:

```
google_name =
      Google::Apis::AdminDirectoryV1::UserName.new(
        given_name: 'John',
        family_name: 'Smith',
        full_name: 'John Smith'
      )
    google_user =
      Google::Apis::AdminDirectoryV1::User.new(
        password: 'password',
        primary_email: 'john.smith@example.com',
        name: google_name,
        change_password_at_next_login: true
      )

  google_user = Google::Apis::AdminDirectoryV1::DirectoryService.new.insert_user(google_user)
```

Comment: I tested the [REST API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/insert) and it did work. Are you signing in with SSO? The documentation says that it doesn't work with that. If that's not the case then it could be an issue with the Ruby gem.